# Operator= and copy c'tor

Tags: c++

```
B j
A i = j
```

while B is derived from A.
my question is this:
what c'tors will be called? A's default c'tor and then A's operator= or A's copy c'tor?
Thanks!

Comment: Write a 10 line class+program and find out?

Comment: No constructors will be called because it won't compile. Beyond that use @WhozCraig suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor, since is a initialization, not an assignment.

From standard C++98 12.8 [class.copy] p1:

> A class object can be copied in two ways, by initialization (12.1,
>   8.5), including for function argument passing (5.2.2) and for function value return (6.6.3), and by assignment (5.17). Conceptually, these
>   two operations are implemented by a copy constructor (12.1) and copy
>   assignment operator (13.5.3).

The redaction looks a bit ambiguous here. May be better the redaction of C++11 (take care of semicolon):

> A class object can be copied or moved in two ways: by initialization
>   (12.1, 8.5), including for function argument passing (5.2.2) and for
>   function value return (6.6.3)**;** and by assignment (5.17). Conceptually,
>   these two operations are implemented by a copy/move constructor (12.1)
>   and copy/move assignment operator (13.5.3).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

public:

    A()
    {
        cout << "(A) default constructor"<< endl;
    }

    A(const A& a)
    {
        cout << "(A) copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        cout << "(A) operator=" << endl;
    }

};

class B : public A
{

public:

    B()
    {
        cout << "(B) default constructor" << endl;
    }


};

int main()
{

    A a1;
    A a2 = a1;
    A a3(a1);

    cout<<"*******"<<endl;

    B b1;

    cout<<"*******"<<endl;

    B b4;
    A a4 = b4;

    return 0;
}

--output:--
(A) default constructor
(A) copy constructor
(A) copy constructor
*******
(A) default constructor
(B) default constructor
*******
(A) default constructor
(B) default constructor
(A) copy constructor
```